# Web Socket Protocol Permission Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I'm trying to connect to a server (locally) using web sockets protocol, so i added ws://*.mychannel.com in chrome manifest file. When debugging i got the following `ws:// is not a valid protocol for manifest, so it will not work`.

Does Chrome allow ws communication ? If yes, how it can be done ?

Comment: You probably don't need protocol definition in manifest. I don't see any in this demo: https://github.com/kinjouj/chrome-extension-background-websocket-demo

Comment: Well, i'm dealing with a third party library that is generating it's own proxy and it have to negotiate with the host before establishing the connection. So connecting to the ws endpoint directly can't be done.

Comment: So... negotiation performs via `ws` protocol also? I think you need to write more detailed question, answer for your initial question is definitely yes, but now you expose new details.

Comment: You don't need special permission to connect to `ws:` URLs, because the browser already allows scripts on any origin to connect to any `ws:` URL by default. Host permissions are generally only necessary when trying to circumvent an origin-based restriction; in this case there is no restriction, even for unprivileged normal webpage scripts.